# Adding file to form

Tags: java, html, servlets

I want to add a file to my form in the servlet without making the user add a file to the form. When I user , i am not able to add the file directly. A selection box appears. Is there any way to add a file directly into the form along with other parameters?
note: the file keeps changing for every form.

Comment: No, for security reason. You definitely don't want a random webpage to get files from your computer without your consent.

Comment: When the client sends a request, i want to attach a file from the server to the form sent by the client

Comment: Show your code. What did you try?

Answer (score 0):

I am basically trying to send a print command to a Xerox machine connected to the network. When i use the following code it sends me a page telling that i need to use a browser that supports frames.
The code which i'm using in the servlet is:

```
    File upFile = new File("path/to/the/file");
    try {
            CloseableHttpClient httpClient = HttpClients.createDefault();
            String authStr= uname+":"+password;
            String encoding = Base64.encode(authStr.getBytes());
            HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("printer's address/UPLPRT.cmd");
            httppost.setHeader("Authorization", "Basic " + encoding);
            FileBody uplFile = new FileBody(upFile);
            StringBody cpn = new StringBody(CPN, ContentType.TEXT_PLAIN);
            StringBody colt = new StringBody(COLT, ContentType.TEXT_PLAIN);
            StringBody dup = new StringBody(DUP, ContentType.TEXT_PLAIN);
            StringBody it = new StringBody(IT, ContentType.TEXT_PLAIN);
            StringBody siz = new StringBody(SIZ, ContentType.TEXT_PLAIN);
            StringBody med = new StringBody(MED, ContentType.TEXT_PLAIN);
            StringBody del = new StringBody(DEL, ContentType.TEXT_PLAIN);
            MultipartEntityBuilder builder = MultipartEntityBuilder.create()
                    .addPart("FILE",uplFile)
                    .addPart("CPN",cpn)
                    .addPart("COLT",colt)
                    .addPart("DUP", dup)
                    .addPart("IT", it)
                    .addPart("SIZ",siz)
                    .addPart("MED",med)
                    .addPart("DEL",del);
    HttpEntity reqEntity= builder.build();
            httppost.setEntity(reqEntity);
    CloseableHttpResponse resp = httpClient.execute(httppost);
    out.println(resp);
    } catch (Exception e) {
            out.println("Exception: Printer Not Responding");
            System.out.println(e);
    }
```

Comment: It worked at last for me. I got it done using htmlunit.